# How to send form textarea data to txt file without submit button?

Tags: php, html

I want the data a visitor copy/pastes or writes into a text area field to be saved to a txt file in the webserver but i can't seem to figure it out.

I have this html so far:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
              <label for="data" class="col-sm-2 control-label">The Data</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                         <textarea id="data" onChange="saveToTxt(this); class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
<script>
function saveToTxt(fld) {
    const textAreaValue = fld.value;
    // then use textArea variable as container of textarea-content
    // and then treat it as you want.
}
</script>
```

The php file to write the txt file:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
   fwrite($handle, $value);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to call the php from the form without the visitor having to push any button.

Any sugestions?

Edit: i have also tried:

```
<script>
function editPhrase() {

    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
    set s   = fso.CreateTextFile("filename.txt", True);

    var phraseChange = document.getElementById('data');

    s.writeline("Phrase :" + phraseChange);

    s.writeline("-----------------------------");
    s.Close();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You can use an ajax request.

Comment: Thx i have searched and searched and did not find a way to make this work with ajax

Comment: Didnt you already ask this twice at least today? Maybe via one of your other accounts??

Comment: @user3833235 You say you "searched and searched".  Did you actually make any attempt?  If you did, please include the attempt(s) in your question along with the result(s).

Comment: I am giving up on this... people take a lot of time to make negative comments but nobody seems to really want to help. Yes, i HAVE searched and tried for 3 days and i can't seem to figure it out. Good luck with all your knowledge, very sad nobody wants to share some knowledge and actually tell me the solution. What a community.....

Comment: Try using the `oninput` event instead of the `onChange`. It will also work when someone copy/pastes text.

Comment: @user3833235 That attitude is not going to get you anywhere.  We're asking you questions to try to clarify your problem.  The purpose of this site is to help you fix your code.  If you're not going to show us the code that you've tried, then we can't help you fix it.  What you have above shows no attempt to make the connection between Javascript and PHP.

Comment: @Hamza Arab tried with oninput, didn't work. That was one of the first things i tried.

Comment: Can you paste the js code you tried?

Comment: @ Patrick Q Exactly, i can not find how to do this

Comment: @ Hamza Arab i have tried function fn(){document.getElementById("form").submit();} amongst other ones

Comment: I editted the post with another method i tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
`$('#data').on('keyup', function() {
var data = $('#data').val();

$.ajax({
    url: './process.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {data: data}
})
});`
```

PHP

```
<?php
$text = $_POST['data'];
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, $text);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, not home now, will try this and report back when i am home.

Comment: Thank you again... i can't figure out how to call the script in the textarea